# How to access object or variable in template of component from component tag in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, components

I have a component which has to render a template based on the value passed through the component tag in HTML. Here is my code 
**This is my sample.js**

```
 (function (angular) {
    "use strict";
    var mod = angular.module("MyModule", []);
    mod.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
        $scope.somevalue=2;
    })
    mod.component("mycomponent", {
        template: function ($attrs) {
            switch ($attrs.tempdata) {
                case 1:
                    return ["<h1>1st page</h1>"];
                case 2:
                    return ["<h1>2nd page</h1>"];
                case 3:
                    return ["{{$ctrl.tempdata}}"]
            }
        },
        bindings: {
            tempdata: '='
        }
    });
})(window.angular);
```

**This is my HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="sample.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyModule" ng-controller="controller">
    <mycomponent tempdata=somevalue></mycomponent>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I need to get the value of tempdata which is passed into the component in the switch. I have used $attrs.tempdata as it will get the value of tempdata as a string which means ($attrs.tempdata="somevalue") . When it is hardcoded for eg as 2 then $attrs.tempdata="2" But I don't need it as a string.
Suggest me a possible solution for it.